# Show Sharepoint incomplete surveys

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-survey-list

I have created Sharepoint survey with "Page Separator" type questions. But, even I am farm admin, I am unable to view responses of an incomplete survey. I need to show total number of participant and how many of them complate survey, how many of them incomplete.

```
I have run this PowerShell. It does not work me, because $unPublishedEntries.Count is always zero
$unPublishedEntries.Count=0
$survey.ItemCount=56
$survey.Items.Count=3



  $web = Get-SPWeb "http://portal.tracy.com/sites/GD/"
$survey = $web.lists["Survey"]
$unPublishedEntries = $survey.Items | ? {-not $_.HasPublishedVersion}

Write-Host "Surveys in list: " $survey.ItemCount
Write-Host "Of which entries are incomplete: " $unPublishedEntries.Count

Foreach ($entry in $unPublishedEntries)
{
    Write-Host $entry["Author"]
}
```

Why I can not see (56-3) 53 users?

Also, I have run this query to check database

```
[sql query][1]
```

But, "tp_level = 255" shows deleted surveys too. If I try "tp_level = 1" it shows complated surveys, but it include deleted surveys too.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi you need to run sql query
This Solution work for me  :
http://yasingokhanyuksel.blogspot.com.tr/2015/11/incomplete-surveys-in-sharepoint.html
Thanks